# Angular - App working in Chrome but not IE

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, internet-explorer

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var moduleServiceUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/lists/getbytitle('Pages')/Items?$select=ID,Title,FileRef,Modules";
        var appVar = angular.module('listApp', []);

        appVar.controller('controller1', function ($scope, $http) {
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: moduleServiceUrl,
                headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }
            }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.items = data.d.results;
                $scope.modules = data.d.results.reduce((modules, item) => {
                    if (item.Modules) {
                        if (Array.isArray(modules[item.Modules])) {
                            modules[item.Modules].push(item);
                        } else {
                            modules[item.Modules] = [item];
                        }
                    }
                    return modules;
                }, Object.create(null));

            });
        })
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <hr />
    <div ng-app="listApp">
        <div id="App1" ng-controller="controller1">
            <div ng-repeat="(module, items) in modules">
                <p><strong>{{module}}</strong></p>
                <p ng-repeat="item in items" style="padding-left:10px;">
                    <a ng-href="{{item.FileRef}}">{{item.Title}}</a>
                </p>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

[IE is showing this error: [$injector:modulerr]](http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=listApp&p1=%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.4.8%2F%24injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3DlistApp)

IE is also saying that "$scope is undefined" although it is a parameter of the function.

This issue is perplexing as the code works fine in chrome.

Comment: This is why I think client side JavaScript frameworks are a terrible idea. Browser hell.

Answer (score 0):

When you do dependency injections you should pass an array of strings to describe the parameters entering the controller function.

1.Best Practice for Angular: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#data-services

```
appVar.controller('controller1', controller1);
controller1.$inject = ['$scope', '$http'];
function controller1($scope, $http) {
     // controller code
}
```

2.Default Angular Pattern: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

```
appVar.controller('controller1', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
     // controller code
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the inline array annotation that angularJS recommanded.

```
appVar.controller('controller1', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
      //Codes          
     }])
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this error occurs due to `Arrow notation` used in [`reduce` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). Arrow notation (ES6 feature) is not supported by IE, follow [Browser Compatibility table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) for a more details.

To make it compatible with IE replace arrow function syntax (`=>`) with function callback syntax:

```
$scope.modules = data.d.results.reduce(function(modules, item){
     if (item.Modules) {
            if (Array.isArray(modules[item.Modules])) {
                 modules[item.Modules].push(item);
            } else {
                 modules[item.Modules] = [item];
            }
     }
     return modules;
}, {});
```